# How can I get User at Validate in Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

In my view(CreateView) I overriding my method def create, but in my validate I cant get logged user by `self.context.get('request').user`, so, how can I get the user logged in my validate?

**UPDATE:**

The Error is:

`line 293, in validate
    user = self.context.get('request').user
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`

**UPDATE 2**

```
class OrderAPIPost(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = MultipleOrderSerializer
    queryset = Order.objects

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       write_serializer = MultipleOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
       write_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       orders = write_serializer.data.get('items')
       orders = list(map(lambda order: Order.create_order(order, self.request.user), orders))
       read_serializer = list(map(lambda order: OrderSerializerList(order), orders))
       read_serializer = list(map(lambda order: order.data, read_serializer))
       return Response(read_serializer, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Show the error message when you try to retrieve the user. Is it the request not present in context or user not in request(very unlikely)? Do you initialize the serializer yourself?

Comment: No, I didn't initiliaze my serializer, I thought to pass User by my view using a mixin, overwriting a methodo like `get_form_kwargs`

Comment: it's really difficult to help you without seeing code samples or the error you got. If everything is done right, the context should have the request with the user in place, even for anonymous users

Comment: post your view code. it seems you are creating the serializer yourself and not passing the context

Comment: ok, wait a minute

Comment: Check my answer below. Don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, from what I can see in your code, you are creating the serializer manually without adding the context. In most cases, allowing the `CreateView` create the serializer by itself suffices but if you really need to create it by yourself, then you need to remember to pass the context. Somthing like this:

```
    context = {'request': self.request}
    write_serializer = MultipleOrderSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
```

You can check the view's `get_serializer()` method to see how a serializer is properly created. I really advice that you refactor your code and try to use the existing solution for creating serializers

Comment: needless to mention that you need to do the same for `OrderSerializerList`

Comment: Nice solution, and great explanation. thanks a lot, I got the problem and I learned how it's work. MultipleOrderSerializer, is a list with OrderSerializerList, so when call MultpleOrderSerializer, all items from that list, will pass to Order, and then `context` too.